# Shut down / start up black screen problem

Tags: shutdown

I'm running dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10.

When I shut down Ubuntu normally starting with clicking the top right gear like symbol [image: e] my computer appears to shut down normally.

When I press the power button on the keyboard I get a black screen.
To start Ubuntu I then need to press the power button for about four seconds to shut down the computer then press it again to get Ubuntu to start normally.

Comment: Oh! I forgot to add that my computer is an ASUS  Zenbook UX305

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste time. I suspected Windows 10 and started it up and then shut it down. That solved my problem. I had some time previously hit restart for Windows 10 and then chose to boot from GRUB my Ubuntu 16.04. Maybe something to do with Windows 10 fast startup.